# I'm stuck on finding how many odd digits are in a number for python

Tags: python-3.x

So we have to write a function in python to count how many digits of a non-negative integer are odd numbers.

```
    def odd_dig(n):
      ans = 0
      for i in range(n):    
        if i in range(n) %2 == 1:
          ans += 1
        elif n[i]==0:
          return None
```

Comment: If you convert n to a string using str you can iterate over the digits more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using range(n) which creates a list from 1 to n. So when you do range(5), in your for loop, you're iterating over 1,2,3,4,5 instead of the actual digits of n.

If you want to find the number of digits you can do something like len(str(n)) which finds the length of the string form of n.

After that, make sure you're using the right operators on the right variables (string operators on strings, list operators on lists, etc...).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know python, but for a solution, why not something like the following?

while n > 0 do these two things:

- add (n%2) to your count
- divide n by 10

because n is defined as non-negative we should be fine with this.